# Error: can't find a register in class 'AREG' while reloading ASM

Tags: gcc, assembly, inline-assembly, rdtsc

When I have executed this code with `b` and `c` variables, then the program will execute but it generates no output. There is some logical error, which does not print the time in output.

```
__inline__ uint64_t timestamp(void)
{
   unsigned long a, b;
   asm volatile ("cpuid; rdtscp" : "=a" (a), "=b" (b) : : "%rax", "%rdx");
   return a | ((uint64_t) b << 32);
}
```

Comment: You've clobbered RAX so it can be used to satisfy the `"=a"` constraint.

Comment: The GCC extended inline-assembly docs tells you how to read the high-res timer. It literally gives you the code. See [6.45.2 Extended Asm - Assembler Instructions with C Expression Operands](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html) in the manual.

Answer (score 1):

How about something like:

```
unsigned int a;

/* 'volatile' prevents gcc from discarding 'unused' function.  */
asm volatile ("cpuid" : "=a" (a) : "a" (0): "rbx", "rcx", "rdx");

/* Use intrinsics when possible.  Ignore 'a', it's garbage.  */
return __builtin_ia32_rdtscp(&a);
```

Although I'm not quite sure why you need cpuid here.  Doesn't rdtscp already wait for all previous instructions to complete?  Did you mean to use cpuid to check and see if rdtscp is supported?

Comment: Yes, that looks like a good way to use the dependency to ensure the compiler puts CPUID before RDTSC.  I agree that CPUID+RDTSCP looks silly.  CPUID+RDTSC is a stronger reordering guarantee than RDTSCP, though, so it can make sense not to always use RDTSCP even when it's available.  [RDTSCP only guarantees that previous instructions have executed, but following instructions can start before it samples the time.](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/RDTSCP.html).  So it's not ideal for serializing at the start of a measurement, but it is ok for measuring the end of a time window.

Comment: Agreed. But silly as it seems, that's what OP said they wanted.  This probably means they aren't quite sure how this works, so hopefully your comment will help clear things up.